# Python-can't detect file from path

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

I develope a script who get a path, read the directory who contain pics and list and store in csv file from most old to most new. 
But the script only work in the same folder where place the pics but not out of the folder. Traceback say:
OSERROR [2] no such directory found: 'picname.jpg'
And it's related with getntime.
It runs in Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7, for aplication Anki2.0
It is the code;

https://github.com/Marcogb81/create-CSV-images-for-anki/blob/master/image_csv_anki.py

Comment: Put the code in the question itself. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must give the absolute path of the picture.

You must change:

```
directory.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
```

to

```
directory.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, x)))
```

Comment: Hello,I follow your instructions , just I add a little change and it's works:              **directory.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(pathf, x)))**

Comment: And now I have this unicode error: ** line 66, in btnImport_clicked
    images = ["<img src='{}/{}'>".format(pathf, elem) for elem in directory]  # give format html for flashcard
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)**

Comment: That error is generated because the names must have tildes or similar symbols.

Comment: Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file.

Comment: After think little bit I found the problem, when I import the photo ,python can not read the title of photo with letter 'ñ'. Y need extend this line with capacity to read ascii code beyond 128 bit.

Comment: In my code I ever put this line. But it is a problem of coding the input in archive, therefore I need extend this line with encode like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: Test with the following command:  `images = ["<img src='{}/{}'>".format(path, elem.encode('utf8')) for elem in directory]  # give format html for flashcard`

Comment: FInally this solution not work. I will find a solution.

Comment: My answer will help you in the initial question, please mark it as correct

Comment: SOrry, I new and noob in Stackoverflow. I apologiced, I give you the solution to problem like good. You are right!

Comment: Try to be concrete in your question, if you have another question create another post, but first you have a search and verify that there is no similar question.

Comment: Finally I solve the line 66 by this: **images = ["<img src='{}/{}'>".format(pathf.encode('utf-8'), elem.encode('utf-8')) for elem in directory]**

Comment: It is a response very similar to mine, I thought the directory did not have those problems.

Comment: Also you confuse me because github uses the variable `path` and you use `pathf`.